# remove packages on centos issue

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, yum

Hi Guys I am getting the follwing output when trying to remove a file on centos. I have tried yum but that hangs for ages I have done my best to google but nothing much comes up. I am able to install and remove other packages except php based ones.

rpm -e --nodeps php-pear-Crypt-Blowfish

(process:15212): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: gtype.c:2458: initialization assertion failed, use IA__g_type_init() prior to this function

(process:15212): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `initialization_value != 0' failed

(process:15212): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed

Thanks in advance,

gda2004

Comment: better asked on superuser.com, anyways, suggestion below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to erase without executing scripts:

```
rpm -e --nodeps --noscripts php-pear-Crypt-Blowfish
```

In case that does not help, figure out if there are process still accessing files from that package. You get the file list using `rpm -ql`. Check with `fuser` whether some files are in use.

Bear in mind that --nodeps and --noscripts may lead to a broken installation, i.e. other packages not working or stuff not properly removed.